# Problems with Error: There was an unexpected Confirmation!

Tags: ide, selenium, selenium-ide, confirmation

I am trying to delete a user from a table. At first I was getting a timeout error but used the BeatnicClick() as described here:

[Selenium IDE click() timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391718/selenium-ide-click-timeout)

That solved the timeout error but I'm still getting the unexpected confirmation error. Here's part of the source code:

> selenium.Click("ctl00_btnAddressBook");
> selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
>
> // selenium.BeatnicClick("ctl00_page_content_ExistingEmployees_ctl03_btnDeleteEmployee");
>
> String Are you sure you want to delete
> the selected item? =
> selenium.GetConfirmation();

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To handle the confirmation your code should look like

```
selenium.Click("ctl00_btnAddressBook"); 
selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
//the IDE code is to get around the IDE bug that it waits on click but it works in Se:RC
selenium.Click("ctl00_page_content_ExistingEmployees_ctl03_btnDeleteEmployee");
//handle the confirmation that appears after the click
string confirmMessage = selenium.GetConfirmation();
//Assert its the correct message
Assert.IsTrue(Regex.IsMatch(confirmMessage,"Are you sure you want to delete the selected item?"));
```

This should click on the delete element and then get the confirm and if you want it can assert its the correct message

Comment: I don't understand your question. I thought you wanted help with Selenium RC. Do you want help with RC or IDE?

Comment: I was initially using IDE but I have switched to Selenium RC. I tried your suggestion in another area and am still getting an error message. I posted the code in the answer below (since it did not fit here)

Comment: If you're using IDE, you need to storeConfirmation before subsequent commands. As described in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062923/selenium-ide-there-was-an-unexpected-confirmation)